# COUNT items when Table1 has one row per item, Table2 has multiple rows for the same item

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

I have the following 2 tables:

Table1: lists transactions by transaction ID (primary key). There is ALWAYS one row per transaction.

Table2: lists transactions by transaction ID (foreign key) plus it shows for each transaction the period in which a specific payment was made. So for one transaction (same transaction ID) there could be multiple rows, for each payment date.

If I join the two tables by their transaction ID, and count the number of transactions, the transactions are not correctly counted as Table1 shows multiple rows for the same transaction (same transaction ID).

COUNT DISCTINCT won’t work in this case as it will still count each row, where transaction ID is the same but payment date is different

I need the join with Table2 as there is a WHERE condition, which is not available in Table1

Any suggestions how I can correctly count the transactions?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: what is DISCTINCT? Do you mean DISTINCT?

Comment: Sorry, I meant DISTINCT

Answer (score 3):

DISTINCT will work - you just have to put the distinct modifier INSIDE of the count and specify the field.

```
select count(distinct table1.transactionid) from table1 join table2 on(table1.transactionid = table2.transactionid);
```

This will provide just 1 row with the total number. If you need to return multiple rows, you will need to add a `group by` clause to suit your purpose. If you don't want to have any grouping at all and want to return all the rows from table2, you need to use analytics / window functions, something like `count(distinct table1.transactionid) over ()`. If you want to first know the total number of distinct transactions and then the results, just do 2 selects.

Comment: Although when you join with `using` you probably can't use `table1.transactionid`

Comment: Ok, that doesn't seem to work when you add a column like payment_date which is different for each month, for example:                                                                                                     
select count (distinct table1.tran_id), table2.payment_date 
where table1.tran_id = table2.tran_id
it will show in this case 3 rows…

Comment: I'm not sure what result you expect -  if you add a column with distinct values and add it to the grouping, of course you will get a different result than the select I suggested. How do you want the resilt to look? Manu rows? One row? In which row do you want the number of transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you join at all? It seems all the information you need is in table2. E.g.:

```
select count(distinct transaction_id)
from table2
where payment_date >= date '2017-01-01';
```